# Can't run spring-boot jar under system user

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

Builded bootJar with gradle. jar work fine on local Mac OS and on Ubuntu server under root user.
Created system user "youtube-dl":

```
youtube-dl:x:109:998::/home/yotube-dl:/usr/sbin/nologin 
uid=109(youtube-dl) gid=998(youtube-dl) groups=998(youtube-dl)
```

and try to execute:

```
sudo -u youtube-dl bash -c "java -jar youtube-dl-1.0.jar"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

I suspect I have lost some Linux settings and the problem isn't with java/spring. Workdir:

```
total 20M
drwxr-xr-x 3 youtube-dl youtube-dl 4.0K Jun 12 14:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root       root       4.0K Jun 12 11:46 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 youtube-dl youtube-dl  367 Jun 12 13:54 app.yaml
drwxr-xr-x 2 youtube-dl youtube-dl 4.0K Jun 12 13:53 keystore/
-rw-r--r-- 1 youtube-dl youtube-dl  20M Jun 12 12:34 youtube-dl-1.0.jar
```

What's my mistake/s?

MRE on petclinic:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git
cd spring-petclinic
./gradlew bootJar
cd builds/libs
apt install openjdk-17-jre
adduser --system spring
addgroup --system spring
addgroup spring spring
sudo -u spring  bash -c "java -jar spring-petclinic-2.6.0.jar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the jar to the root directory, this was the problem. I moved the jar from /root/app to /home/spring and now the jar runs under the spring user.